# Peer to peer spreadsheet application in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, p2p

I have a college project where I need to extend an existing spreadsheet application ([CleanSheets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csheets/) - open source).

Right now, it's just a simple spreadsheet application. What I was asked to implement is a menu option that allows a user to share a sheet (i.e. the user selects 'share a sheet' - it's the current one - and then selects the area that they wish to share: A1:A9, for example). Then they can specify a local port and the share is created.

The other users who wish to connect to that share will have to know the machine's IP and the port to connect. Once they input that info under a menu option called 'join a shared sheet' then that shared area will appear in their current sheet, and they are free to edit and view what others are typing in those cells.

Everyone has read/write access - that must be controlled by threads (because we can have 1 person sharing and 3 peers connected to that sheet, all viewing the changes and making their own). Multiple exclusion will have to be guaranteed (this can be done with Semaphores and/or Reentrantlocks).

The sharing implementation has to implemented in a peer to peer architecture.

Now my question is: how to I start developing with sockets in Java? I've read some documentation in Java, especially about JXTA, but that's most likely not what I need. I don't need a complex P2P application, just that sharing ability.

I'm assuming I need to use UDP (because TCP is mostly server-client, and anyone can be a server or a client here) and I don't need packet control. I already know about sockets in C. Which classes should I use in Java related to sockets?

Comment: [Java Tutorial on Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: I looked at that tutorial, but mostly it covers client/server sockets. I don't really want that - my application can be run on any computer, any person can create a share. They don't all connect to a dedicated server.

Comment: @Lovato: that basically just means that every copy of the program has both client and server code. Sharing a spreadsheet uses the "server" code and connecting to a shared spreadsheet uses the "client" code.

Comment: @JerryCoffin So does that mean I use TCP or UDP sockets, or that doesn't really matter for my case?

Comment: @Lovato: it's orthogonal to TCP vs. UDP. Under the circumstances, UDP might (very well) make more sense though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks. So if I got this right: -selects to share, invoke server code, wait for connections in a separate thread so you don't block the main app- The other: -selects to join, invoke client code-. However, the server can also edit (for example, if the user creating the share wants to edit), will the changes be reflected to all the other clients?

Comment: @Lovato: yes, that's what you'd normally want to do anyway. To do this, the server typically tracks the clients that have the share open, and sens out updates to each. When a client makes a change, it sends that to the server, then the server sends it out to all the others. If you can use it, Java Messaging Service may be helpful here.

Comment: @JerryCoffin So basically, I can assume that Java Messaging Service is similar to sending out a broadcast packet in C?

Comment: @Lovato: Kind of, but (if memory serves) it puts more emphasis on dependability that timeliness, so it uses TCP instead of UDP. Perhaps more importantly, it can work across routers, firewalls, etc., where broadcast packets won't go.

Comment: Can you only share one section at a time or does it have to be able to share multiple blocks at at time?  That will affect your design.  I think the sockets tutorial is what you should be looking at, regardless.  I don't think UDP is a good idea for this.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think JMS is meant more of a replacement for the client/server model, from what I read, and my project requires me to use threads, sockets and IPs. I guess, since the objects are syncronized with locks - every time someone edits, the server knows what was edited and sends the necessary changes via the sockets connected to each client. Example: user1 edits cell content A1 from 'a' to 'hello'. user 2 (who created the share) and user 3 are connected, so user2 sends to user1, and user1 knows what was edited, so it sends it in broadcast to every single client.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Sorry, typo. I meant user1 sends to user 2 (user2 created the share) and user2 knows what was edited and sends in broadcast (it's the server).

Comment: @BenBrunk But isn't UDP meant for P2P? The requisites say 'must be implemented in a P2P socket architecture in Java'. So I assumed UDP. And you only share one section at a time. You can't create multiple shared blocks.

Comment: Yes, if you're required to use threads, sockets, and IPs, then JMS doesn't fit (it abstracts most of that away).

Comment: UDP does not send an "ack" for each packet received.  It is a best effort protocol.  It is intended for streaming applications where speed is important and dropping some data is "acceptable" in the sense that you wouldn't want to go back and insert a frame of video if it got dropped a few seconds ago.  That's UDP.  I don't think you want it for what you are doing.  Peer-to-peer isn't really a protocol, it's a technique, what they are telling you is that they don't expect you to build a central server but rather your app becomes the server when it is sharing data.  JMS doesn't fit here at all.

Comment: @BenBrunk Thank you, I developed it using TCP Java sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.io and java.net have some useful classes you might want to look at. This is a pretty simplified example because I've ignored catching/throwing but hopefully it'll sort of show  what you can do for tx/rx.

write bytes ought to be able to take in something serializable.

Send data:

```
// create connection
Socket cs = new Socket(<dest-hostname>, <port-num>);
DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream() );

// send stuff
ds.writeBytes("is this thing on?");

// close socket and stream
cs.close();
cs = null;
ds = null;

Receive data:
ServerSocket listenSocket;
Socket s = listenSocket.accept();
BufferedReader receivedThing = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( s.getInputStream() ) );

//assuming its plaintext
String msg = receivedThing.readLine();

// close the socker/serversocket
```

hope this helps.